# What is the difference between twisted.protocols.basic.LineReceiver and twisted.internet.protocol.Protocol?

Tags: python, sockets, network-programming, protocols, twisted

For a typical client-server based application, how do the two differ from each other. Specifically, what is special with a line-based protocol? Even better, when does a class have to inherit from `Protocol` and when from `LineReceiver`?

Comment: What do you expect as an answer other than the obvious that the difference between `LineReceiver` and `Protocol` is that the former declares `lineReceived()/sendLine()` methods (+ related functionality) that allow you to avoid reimplementing receiving/sending lines in each of your protocols whenever you need it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Difference becomes by received data handling.

Protocol have dataReceived function. It will be called whenever data received.

LineReceiver overrides Protocol. It is implements a basic messaging format that messages separated with ' \r\n'.

Let's assume server writes messages like;

```
request.write("Lorem ipsum")
request.write("do amet siempre.\r\n")
request.write("We have Drogba!\r\n")
```

Messaged received on the Client side with implements Protocol;

```
def dataReceived(self, data):
   print data
.
.
output:

Lorem ipsum
do amet siempre.
We have Drogba!
```

Messaged received on the Client side with implements LineReceiver;

```
def lineReceived(self, line):
   print line
.
.
output: 
Lorem ipsum do amet siempre.
We have Drogba!
```

I hope it is helpful. For more information you can look [reference](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.protocols.basic.LineReceiver.html) or comment to ask.

Comment: request.write("Drogba var da noluyo")